# Creating a ConcurrentQueue of objects in managed c++/.net 4.0

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed-c++

I've been trying to update some managed c++ code I inherited.  I don't know any c++, but I took a c# class in back in the 1.1 days, so I can kind of find my way around .Net.  So far, I've had good results using ConcurrentQueue's to send work to worker threads from my main thread:

```
fullQueue = gcnew ConcurrentQueue<int>();

..

fullQueue->Enqueue(someNumber);
```

Now I'd like to try inserting actual objects so that I can send workers more complicated instructions.  However, this does not work:

```
public ref class workUnit
{
    int ptrOffset;
    System::String^ outputPath;
    public:
        workUnit(int offset, System::String^ path)
        {
            ptrOffset=offset;
            outputPath=path;
        }
};
```

..

```
ConcurrentQueue test = gcnew ConcurrentQueue<workUnit ^>();
```

I get:

```
'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentQueue' : use of class generic requires generic argument list

'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentQueue::ConcurrentQueue' : the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentQueue<T> ^'
```

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental about how objects are inserted into the queue.  In my head, I think I'm making a queue that will hold references to class objects I can instantiate later, so the CLR should just need to know what reference type will go in, but apparently this is not correct.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've missed something :)

```
using namespace System::Collections::Concurrent;

ref class WorkUnit
{
};

int main()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<WorkUnit^>^ test = gcnew ConcurrentQueue<WorkUnit^>();
}
```

You must reference the generics type **<WorkUnit^>** in both sides of the initialisation expression.